# Deploy an Elastic Kubernetes Cluster with Openstack

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, openstack

I am working on a Cloud provider named Wekeo, which offers only static provisionning of instances. I have access to the Morpheus API and the underlying OpenStack API.

My goal is to deploy an elastic cluster (EKS for instance), but I'm getting lost through the many concepts and tools I found so any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: This is too vague, what exactly have you tried and where does it fail?

Comment: @eblock So far I've read tons of articles praising various tools to combine openstack and kubernetes (I remember terraform, rancher...) and I'm really confused because none of them seemed to apply to my use case as I am not administrator of the underlying Openstack architecture, only user of this cloud...